# Use date() variable

Tags: php, date

I want to echo my var.

For example:

```
<?php
  echo $MONTH09;  // Return September
?>
```

I need to bulid it like this:

```
<?php
  echo $$."MONTH".date('m');
?>
```

But it does not work.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the variable variable (`$$`) intentional? Also, PHP does not support `.` as object notation, so is the `.` meant for concatenating a string?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using an array to store the month names?

Comment: Cause it's a multilingual system.

Comment: How does that explain why you can’t use an array instead of variables with an index in their _name_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
echo ${'MONTH' . date('m')};
```

But better way to print month is:

```
echo date('F');
```